# Invalid ID Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am facing very odd behavior of Laravel 5.2 Eloquent. When I try to insert a row in my table it returns an object which have incremented ID. Now the issue is, the ID it return is not the ID of that row.

e.g.

My Code:

```
    DB::beginTransaction();

    //create a new product
    $product_p = new Product();
    $product_p->name = $request->name;
    $product_p->barcode = $request->barcode;
    $product_p->sale_price = $request->sale_price;
    $product_p->save();
    echo $product_p->id; //this gives invalid ID    
    DB::commit();
```

When I try to access `$product_p->id` it returns 31 even though the product id in the database is 5.

I have developed sync controller which is responsible to make record of every query executed, ON further investigation I found the sync controller id is responsible for invalid ID.

My Route File

```
// SyncController
\Event::listen('Illuminate\Database\Events\QueryExecuted', function ($query)      {
   $sync = new \App\Http\Controllers\SyncController();
   $sync->addOperation($query->sql, $query->bindings);
});
```

My Sync Controller

```
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $sync = New Sync();
        $sync->action = $sql;
        $sync->data = json_encode($data);
        $sync->save();
    DB::commit();
```

My DB Structure for product

```
id Primary  int(10)     UNSIGNED    AUTO_INCREMENT
name        varchar(255)
barcode     int(11)
sale_price  int(11)
```

This is my Product Migration

```
        Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $table) {
          $table->increments('id');
          $table->string('name');
          $table->integer('barcode')->unique();
          $table->integer('sale_price');
          $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: Is it possible you are using a different databases?

Comment: nopes. I am using Product Model.

class Product extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = ['name', 'barcode', 'sale_price'];
  protected $table = "products";


and I am checking **products** table

Comment: I think you should consider updating your post so as to make it complete. The current information you provided is not enough to simulate and or troubleshoot effectively the challenge you are facing. Also, make sure you label your file contents accordingly for easy distinction. A screenshot of your table and or script may equally be helpful.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code for your `Product` model and the code for your `XXX_XXX_create_products_table.php` migration file? I want to see if there are any relations that might be affecting it

Comment: @nyedidikeke I have updated my question with more information.

I haven't made any relation with my product or sync tables. No foreign key, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this at store method in Controller.**

```
$input_data = $request->all();
$last_inserted_data = YourModelName::create($input_data);
dd($last_inserted_data)
```

Check the output from dd()

Comment: same issue. it return same. I tried rerun migration and my ID starts from 5 whereas it starts from 1 in database.